# Powershell WPF checkbox binding

Tags: wpf, powershell, checkbox

I have a MenuItem Checkbox in my main window as well as in another two windows:

```
    <MenuItem x:Name = 'FileMenu' Header = '_File'>
        <MenuItem x:Name = 'EnableAutostart' Header = '_Enable Autostart' IsChecked="{Binding AutoStart, Mode= TwoWay}" IsCheckable="true" ToolTip = 'Enables the autostart.' InputGestureText ='Ctrl+S'></MenuItem>
```

I use it to define whether or not the script automatically starts on user logon (a function checks for the scheduled activity and sets the checkbox accordingly) and when clicked it enables or disables it.

Now what if I want to keep all the 3 different windows checkboxes synced?

I read a lot about binding but can't really get it working, I tried to set the binding on a bool "Autostart" and to set it true before showing the window but it does nothing at all.

How can I define a bool in my code and make it so that, whenever I change that bool, it reflects on all the menuitems checkboxes bound to it? (even if the other windows are yet to be created/shown)

I read about needing to make it a property... can I just make a class, set a property to it called something like "AutoStart" and it would work?

Comment: I've been able to databind WPF items to PSCustomObjects. The biggest problem I've noticed however was the lack of an easy usable implemention of INotifyPropertyChanged in Powershell (so the GUI doesn't get notified that the state has changed and won't update the data in a lot of cases). Because of this I nowadays embed a small C# class in my scripts with a simple viewmodel to make this easier.

Comment: Answering here to make sure you get notified, read my answer and the articles i linked, feels damn easy to me, maybe it works for you aswell ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @bluuf, you kind of gave me a hint.

Anyway comes out i actually achieved to do a databind previously in my many tests but as you said, the INotifyPropertyChanged is not so easy to handle in powershell, or maybe it is?

Good guy Trevor Jones (link at bottom) explained an easy way and i did the last steps to understand it and apply it to my code. Thank you Trevor.

He basically explains that this one collection:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Object]
```

Has an already implemented iNotifyPropertyChanged that works well in powershell, without adding c# classes.

You just create that collection, add your bool to it, and point the binding.source to it.

Trevor's article, actually read it, worth your time:
https://smsagent.blog/2017/02/03/powershell-deepdive-wpf-data-binding-and-inotifypropertychanged/

P.S. Trevor also points to this article which explains how to implement the c# class (and more), if anyone is interested:
https://www.ephingadmin.com/better-know-a-powershell-ui-50-shades-of-bindings-part-1/

Comment: I've used the observablecollection in the past. While it does suit the needs in most cases but in more advanced scenario's it was just too much of a pain compared to using some C# because you have to work with an array and databind the the first element in it. (You can actually create a Powershell class where you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in Powershell including the event, but because you can't make custom getters and setters it was useless)